# SVPullToRefresh + SVInfiniteScrolling in Swift code

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, swift, ios8

Im using SVPullToRefresh + SVInfiniteScrolling on swift code base. How do I write

```
[tableView addPullToRefreshWithActionHandler:^{
    // prepend data to dataSource, insert cells at top of table view
    // call [tableView.pullToRefreshView stopAnimating] when done
}];
```

and

```
[tableView addPullToRefreshWithActionHandler:^{
    // prepend data to dataSource, insert cells at top of table view
    // call [tableView.pullToRefreshView stopAnimating] when done
} position:SVPullToRefreshPositionBottom];
```

in swift code ?

Answer (score 1):

try something like:

```
self.tableView.addPullToRefreshWithActionHandler({() -> Void in
    //code       
})
```

Answer (score 1):

```
myTableView.addPullToRefreshWithActionHandler({() -> Void in

}
```

remember to add SVPullToRefresh to your briding header file e.g. "MyProject-Bridging-Header.h

```
#import <SVPullToRefresh/SVPullToRefresh.h>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
tableView.addPullToRefreshWithActionHandler {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

can be:

```
myTableView.addPullToRefresh(actionHandler: {

})

myTableView.addInfiniteScrolling(actionHandler:
            {() -> Void in

        })
```

Swift now is cutting name of first argument from function name. And as  mentioned by Robert you need to include this header in your Bridging file.